# "apt-get install" does not ask for confirmation as "yum install"

Tags: linux, yum, apt-get

When using `yum install firefox` it will ask me for confirmation if I would really like to do it, but `apt-get install firefox` it will not ask me. Is there a way that it will ask me? Thank you

Comment: `apt-get` will generally ask for confirmation, unless you have configured it not to. Check `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apt-get will only ask for confirmation in certain cases (if other packages are pulled or if installed packages are modified or removed); see [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/287357) for details.

To always see what apt-get is going to do before actually installing it, you may use the -s (simulate) flag.

```
apt-get -s install firefox
```

apt-get will tell you what it would do when installing firefox, but would not actually do it. If you are satisfied you can then run the install command again without the simulate flag.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get by default needs root privileges to run. If you type `apt-get install firefox` it should ask you about root privileges. `sudo apt-get firefox` should prompt you for your password. So as you can see, it's an indirect way of asking for confirmation. It cannot install anything unless you confirm your password.